# Reference specific row's column value from array

Tags: php, mysql

I have read a-lot of answers on this but they don't seem to be working.

I have the following code:

```
$amountoflikes=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `uc_likes` WHERE `dwable` =  '372'");
```

This returns the following:

[image]

If I wanted to echo the value of `dwable` in the 2nd row for instance (not involving the initial query).

I've tried:

```
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($amountoflikes)){
    $json[] = $row3;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
```

But this returns null.

I'm currently using PHP 5.5 (native).

I'm not using MySQLi or MySQL PDO.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong. Ideally I'd prefer not to use a loop but I don't know if that's possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried echo $json[1]['dwable'] in place of your existing echo?

Comment: @Craig just tried it now and nothing appeared.

Comment: You need the loop if there are multiple records. Have you tried `echo $row3['dwable'];`? If you are doing `\`dwable\` =  '372'` why even execute the query you know `dwable` will be `372`.

Comment: @chris85 it turns out I think my initial query wasn't returning results with the variables (even though I echoed them out to check).

Comment: @Ben So issue resolved?

Comment: Yes @chris85 not sure whether to delete or not. Will probably keep open as adding $json = array(); did help me realise the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring $json as an array above the while:

```
$json = array();
```

Comment: It turns out my initial query wasn't returning results with the variables in it (even though I echoed them out to check). However since I added this it changed from Null to [] which made me think this was the case. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

declare your array as follows

```
$json = array();
```

and see if you have results before your result

```
if ($amountoflikes)
{
  while(){...}
}
```